# Making separators uniform in BibTex bibliography

Tags: bibtex, custom-bib

Using `latex makebst` plus a bit of fiddling with the resulting .bst file, I've managed to get my bibliography close to the shape I want it to be in.  The exception is for certain `incollection` and `inproceedings` fields.  At the moment I'm getting entries like this:

> Smith, John (2016), An article about things.  In Joe Bloggs (ed.), *A book about things*, number 12 in A Series of Books.  Publisher.  City, 123–321.

What I want is for the entry to look like this:

> Smith, John (2016), An article about things.  In Joe Bloggs (ed.), *A book about things*.  Number 12 in A Series of Books.  Publisher.  City.  123–321.

That is to say, in some locations I'm getting commas as separators where I want full stops.  It's set up with natbib as the author-year support system and with `\newblock` between blocks, if that information helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, it turns out that the part of the .bst file that I wanted to change is `FUNCTION {output.nonnull}`.  Specifically, I've changed

```
output.state mid.sentence =
  { ", " * write$ }
```

to

```
output.state mid.sentence =
  { ". " * write$ }
```

This has caused some problems with capitalization elsewhere, but I have decided to hack through them at this point.